# On the inverse of a composition of two bijections

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Please help me proving the following theorem.

> $f:S \to T$ is a bijection and $h : T\to V$ is a bijection implies that $(h\circ f)^{-1} = f^{-1}\circ h^{-1}$ is a bijection too.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese:I am sorry،
nothing:(

Comment: Instead of typing in o for composition lol, use something like \circle. Well played though :)

Comment: Do you know what it means for a function to be a bijection?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese: yes but I can not prove it.

Comment: If you have not tried anything, how do you know you can't prove it? Can you prove that $h\circ f$ is a bijection?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese: yes.I can prove that $h$ o $f$ is a bijection but I am not shure.

Comment: _Any function_ defined as the inverse of another function is a bijection. But that other function needs to be proven a bijection before one is allowed to talk about its inverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides to Lays's good points, since $h:T\to V$ is a bijective map, so is the $h^{-1}:V\to T$ (Why?).We have the same story for $f^{-1}:T\to S$. We note that $f^{-1}\circ h^{-1}$ is a bijective map. Hint for one-one case:

Let $f^{-1}\circ h^{-1}(t_1)=f^{-1}\circ h^{-1}(t_2)$ so since both of $f^{-1}\circ h^{-1}(t_i)\in S$ so $f$ can act on them as: $$f(f^{-1}\circ h^{-1}(t_1))=f(f^{-1}\circ h^{-1}(t_2))$$ and so $$(f\circ f^{-1})\circ h^{-1}(t_1)=(f\circ f^{-1})\circ h^{-1}(t_2)$$ and so ... and therefore $t_1=t_2$.

Comment: :Thanks, this is really the best answer :)

Comment: But you should complete it.

Comment: You look good in $\color{green}{\bf \large green \checkmark}$

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks mu dearest friend.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Do you know the definition of a bijection? You must prove that it is both sujective and one-one.

1. **one-one**: $F(x)=F(y)\implies x=y$
2. **surjective**: for all $b\in B$ there is some $a\in A$ such that $f(a)=b$.

Let $t,v\in h$ and and $t',v\in h$ and since $f$ is a bijection $\exists$  $s,s' \in S$ such that $s,t \in f$ and $s',t'\in f$ ...

Comment: :+Thanks for your help.
please Help me to be more.tnx